# Is latest reactJS version compatible with all 0.58.x versions of React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to understand the design of reactjs library with the direction of react-native versioning. Is React native suppose to be backward compatible with specific ReactJS versions? What is the rule of thumb when I want to upgrade react-native? Do I need to specify a specific version of ReactJS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: reactjs for web, and react native for mobile, why would you want to speficy a reactjs version for mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

React Native and ReactJS are separate javascript frameworks. They make look similar but they do not affect or depend on each other. React Native is used to build ios / android apps and ReactJS is used to build web apps. You cannot move code between the 2 frameworks.